# regex check for Float number -> not ending and stars with decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

I am facing issues with regex pattern for Float number -> that should not end or stars with decimal points..

I have tried following regex patter.. that is

```
regex = /^\d*\.?\d*$/
```

//    on doing

```
regex.test(11.) 
regex.test(.11)
```

// it is returning true in checking

//    I need to make this as false, comment will be much helpful
thank you.

Comment: That is because all parts are optional. You can use `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` to match an optional dot and digits.

Comment: hey @Thefourthbird can you correct me if you can?
because I need to understand it. Thanks!

Comment: In your pattern you use `*` which means 0 or more, and `?` which means 0 or 1. So it can match for example also a single dot or an empty string. So you have to match at least a single digit, followed by an optional part matching a dot and digits so it can also not end on a dot only. There are examples like this page which have examples and explanations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2

Comment: `11.` will get parsed as `"11"` string and `.11` as `"0.11"`. Pass the values as strings and use `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`.

Comment: it seems i needs to put 5hrs to understand regex concept..

Comment: Regex only operates on strings, so all numbers you pass to it are coerced to strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bear in mind that regex only works with strings. When you pass a non-string variable as input to a `RegExp`, it will first coerce it to a string type.

Have a look:

```js
console.log(11. , 'and', .11); // => 11 and 0.11
```

So, the actual string values you pass to your `^\d*\.?\d*$` regex are `11` and `0.11` that  can be matched with the given pattern. Actually, `^\d*\.?\d*$` is a regex that is usually used for a very loose live number input validation, e.g. see [How to make proper Input validation with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425087).

What you want is to implement a final, on-submit validation pattern, so that it could not pass *strings* like `11.` and `.11`. There have been lots of threads discussing this kind of regex:

- [Regular expression for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643009/regular-expression-for-floating-point-numbers)
- [regular expression for finding decimal/float numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256061/regular-expression-for-finding-decimal-float-numbers)

Basically, for validation, you will need something like

```js
/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(input_string)
/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/.test(input_string)
/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/.test(input_string)  // Some need to only allow 1 or 2 fractional digits
/^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$/.test(input_string) // 1-3 digits in the integer part and two required in the fractional part
```

Comment: much helpful

but what 

console.log()
does internally means to convert the things in magic manner!

Comment: @AnupamMaurya You might be interested in [JavaScript type coercion explained](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/)